# What sensor would I use to get the speed or velocity of my Arduino based nav system?

Tags: arduino-nano

I'm building a Arduino Nano based underwater navigation system using an IMU and various sensors. The only problem with this is that I cannot get the speed or velocity(at least reliably) and it would help the accuracy of my navigation system immensely if I had accurate speed to go off of.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could measure the speed of my Arduino underwater? I've seen some people recommend paddle wheel like sensors but this needs to be accurate for slow movement.

Comment: As commented on your previous question, this is a problem usually solved with sonar.  A flow sensor can be useful, but outside of a stagnant body of water like a swimming pool or tank with no filtering system or a small pond, velocity relative to the water is not necessarily the same as velocity relative to fixed items.

Answer (score 1):

On small recreational sailboats there is a small propeller on the bottom, when it turns it dials a speedometer, the faster it turns the faster the ship goes, a similar setup should be possible. With a small propeller and 2 ball bearings and an optocoupler, (same principle you got in the scroll button on your mouse, you should be able to pull it off with minimal resistance since there is no physical parts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want accurate data (i.e. not by dead reckoning) then possibly GPS is an option. I suspect you will need to surface for it to work, as GPS signals are fairly week at the best of times - on a previous car I had, the windscreen was enough to stop the signal.

Comment: That makes it rather impractical for "underwater" speed determination, no?